# Display max value of an y bar stacked plot

Tags: pgfplots

The following MWE generates an y bar stacked plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
                   ybar stacked,
                   enlargelimits=0.15,
                   xlabel={Number of cores},
                   xtick={12},
                   ylabel={Cores load (\%)},
                   ymin=0, ymax=100,
                   ]
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=red] plot coordinates { (12,3.53)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=green!40] plot coordinates { (12,8.34)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=blue] plot coordinates { (12,6.76)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=cyan] plot coordinates { (12,4.6)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=magenta] plot coordinates { (12,9.5)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=yellow] plot coordinates { (12,14.45)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=gray] plot coordinates { (12,26.12)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=purple] plot coordinates { (12,8.45)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=orange] plot coordinates { (12,9.75)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=brown] plot coordinates { (12,3.18)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=red!40] plot coordinates { (12,4.87)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=green] plot coordinates { (12,0.46)};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A bar represents one time range divided in X sub ranges. For clarity, on this example only the bar 12 is shown. The value for each sub range represents the percentage of time spent in this range and so the total of sub ranges is 100%. I want to display (on top of the bar, or maybe inside the sub-range rotated) the maximum value among the sub ranges percentages. How should I acheive this ?

Comment: So you want to show `12(100%)` above the bar?

Comment: Or on top of the bar?  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179752/conditional-alignment-of-labels-in-pgfplots-bar-chart?s=2|1.0672 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172814/tikz-stacked-bar-chart-with-text?s=58|0.1056

Comment: @HarishKumar no sorry I was not clear, I want to show (26.12%) on top of the bar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some remarks

- `compat=1.12` is essential, otherwise the metadata would be the cumulated value instead of the true value.

  - that is, the top one is always the largest one with result 100%)
  - I am not saying it is **necessary**. Just somehow I do not want to chase where the difference comes from.
- `nodes near coords` is essential, and is not necessary as long as you want to draw/place the node yourself.
- `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` ranges from 0 to 1000. So checking if it is larger than 999 will probably indicate the largest datapoint.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
                   ybar stacked,
                   enlargelimits=0.15,
                   xlabel={Number of cores},
                   xtick={12},
                   ylabel={Cores load (\%)},
                   ymin=0, ymax=100,
                   nodes near coords={
                      \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt>999pt
                         \kern50pt\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%
                      \fi
                   }
                   ]
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=red] plot coordinates { (12,3.53)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=green!40] plot coordinates { (12,8.34)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=blue] plot coordinates { (12,6.76)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=cyan] plot coordinates { (12,4.6)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=magenta] plot coordinates { (12,9.5)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=yellow] plot coordinates { (12,14.45)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=gray] plot coordinates { (12,26.12)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=purple] plot coordinates { (12,8.45)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=orange] plot coordinates { (12,9.75)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=brown] plot coordinates { (12,3.18)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=red!40] plot coordinates { (12,4.87)};
         \addplot+[ybar, black, fill=green] plot coordinates { (12,0.46)};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```